# how to disable taking screen shot capability in selenium webdriver using java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to disable the capability of taking screen shots in selenium webdriver using `DesiredCapabilities` class? I tried the below code setting the capability to false and then called a function to take screen shot. It does not work i.e. it does not disable from taking screen shots

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("takesScreenShot", false);

WebDriver oBrowser = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
oBrowser.get(baseUrl);

CommonLibs.library1.getScreenShot(oBrowser);
```

Comment: There is no such property name called `takesScreenShot`. So, no surprise if it does not work! Also, I do not think there is a way to _disable_ screenshot as its not a feature of WebDriver per se that you can enable or disable.

Comment: Why don't you comment/remove the code that actually takes the screenshot instead of looking for a way to disable it? Or if you want it to be conditional, maybe you can add screenshot logic inside a `if` condition!

Comment: actually i read in a book on selenium that one can set the "takesScreenShot" capability using DesiredCapabilities class setting it to true. So I thought that does setting it to false disable it. Thanks for your answer. Could you please explain me the exact use of DesiredCapabilities class please?

Comment: @Tammay Baid, I can see ```"takesScreenshot": true``` in the browser capabilities of a firefox session. It would be good to have the option to turn off as all failure responses are having an embedded screenshot, making them hard to read.